# RJ11 socket in Eagle libraries?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, telephone, socket

I am trying to add RJ11 (telephone wire) sockets to my PCB on Eagle but am having trouble finding it in the libraries.  Is this a standard socket that is included or do I need to install some external library?  If the latter, where can I find such a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sparkfun releases many of the parts](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries) used in their products in the form of the footprint and schematic symbol.  It seems like they have an RJ11 connector in their connections library.  You can download them from the linked github page.

As for more Eagle library resources:

- Adafruit also [releases their eagle parts](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Eagle-Library) as well, although I'm not sure if they have an RJ11 connector.
- I have [published and maintain my own as well](https://github.com/funkyguy4000/Circuit-Boards/blob/master/Strutz%20Electronic%20Industries.lbr), although I take great care to make sure they are correct, they are still unverified so take them w/ a grain of salt.

Generally if you can't find the part, you'd have to make it yourself.  There are [many tutorials](https://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=Eagle) explaining how to make a part in Eagle.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with a missing component is to make your own.

1. Find a component that meets your spec.
2. Draw a schematic symbol for it.
3. Draw a PCB footprint.
4. Marry the two as a component.
5. Place the component you created in your design.

Relying on third party libraries is not good practice. Unless you check every part, you cannot be certain that the pin mapping is correct, or the part will match the footprint.

Answer (score 0):

The SparkFun connectors library has a footprint + schematic for an rj11 socket that they sell. I doubt there's such a thing as a generic rj11 socket.

https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries